# Python request gets Json response with some fields encoded incorrectly

Tags: python, json, python-requests, character-encoding

On a project I'm working on when I make a request to get EPG data from the server, The title and description in the Json response are garbled text. Initial I though this might an encoding problem but tried decoding/encoding the text in various formats and no success.

Anyways heres the code for fetching the request with some debug output:

```
def get_short_epg(profile, stream_id, limit=1):
    epg_url = build_url("{0}/player_api.php".format(profile['server']),
                        {'username': profile['username'], 'password': profile['password'],
                         'action': 'get_short_epg', 'stream_id': stream_id, 'limit': limit})
    response = requests.get(epg_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        if profile['debug']:
            print(response.encoding)
            print(response.apparent_encoding)
            print(response.request.headers)
            print(response.json())
            print(response.content)

        data_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'data')
        output_file= os.path.join(data_dir, 'short_epg.json')
        f = open(output_file, 'w')
        f.write(response.text)
        f.close()
    else:
        print("Failed with status code {0}".format(response.status_code))
```

Which produces the following output:

> None
> ascii
> {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
> {'epg_listings': [{'id': '1037932301', 'epg_id': '34', 'title': 'QnJpdGFpbidzIEdvdCBUYWxlbnQ=', 'lang': 'en', 'start': '2020-10-03 20:00:00', 'end': '2020-10-03 22:00:00', 'description': 'QW50IGFuZCBEZWMgaG9zdCB0aGUgZmlmdGggc2VtaS1maW5hbCBvZiB0aGlzIHllYXIncyB0YWxlbnQgY29udGVzdCwgd2VsY29taW5nIGJhY2sgdGhlIGFjdHMgdGhhdCBpbXByZXNzZWQgdGhlIGp1ZGdlcyBkdXJpbmcgdGhlIGF1ZGl0aW9ucyBlcGlzb2RlcyBpbiB0aGUgc3ByaW5nLiBBbWFuZGEgSG9sZGVuLCBBbGVzaGEgRGl4b24sIERhdmlkIFdhbGxpYW1zIGFuZCBBc2hsZXkgQmFuam8gYXJlIG9uIHRoZSBqdWRnaW5nIGRlc2su', 'channel_id': 'ITV London', 'start_timestamp': '1601751600', 'stop_timestamp': '1601758800'}]}
> b'{"epg_listings":[{"id":"1037932301","epg_id":"34","title":"QnJpdGFpbidzIEdvdCBUYWxlbnQ=","lang":"en","start":"2020-10-03 20:00:00","end":"2020-10-03 22:00:00","description":"QW50IGFuZCBEZWMgaG9zdCB0aGUgZmlmdGggc2VtaS1maW5hbCBvZiB0aGlzIHllYXIncyB0YWxlbnQgY29udGVzdCwgd2VsY29taW5nIGJhY2sgdGhlIGFjdHMgdGhhdCBpbXByZXNzZWQgdGhlIGp1ZGdlcyBkdXJpbmcgdGhlIGF1ZGl0aW9ucyBlcGlzb2RlcyBpbiB0aGUgc3ByaW5nLiBBbWFuZGEgSG9sZGVuLCBBbGVzaGEgRGl4b24sIERhdmlkIFdhbGxpYW1zIGFuZCBBc2hsZXkgQmFuam8gYXJlIG9uIHRoZSBqdWRnaW5nIGRlc2su","channel_id":"ITV London","start_timestamp":"1601751600","stop_timestamp":"1601758800"}]}'

Saved the json output to a file as suspect it may be a case the just the title and description text provided in the json are encoded diffrently.Tried encoding/decoding the title value loaded using the below:

```
    list = json.load(open('data/short_epg.json'))
    title = list['epg_listings'][0]['title']
    print(title.encode())
    for enc in encodings.aliases.aliases:
        for enc2 in encodings.aliases.aliases:
            try:
                test = title.encode(enc2).decode(enc)
                if test not in title:
                    print('{0} to {1} = {2}'.format(enc2, enc, test))
            except:
                pass
```

But the only results that resulted in different output were the encondings for chinese/arabic. Also tried diffrent servers, in case it was isolated issue but getting the same garbled data each time.

Just for refrence the title value of "QnJpdGFpbidzIEdvdCBUYWxlbnQ=" should be "Britain's Got Talent" anyone have any idea on which incorrect encoding this is or how to get the correct text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. `QnJpdGFpbidzIEdvdCBUYWxlbnQ=` becomes `Britain's Got Talent`

you can use the python [base64 lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) to decode this.

```
import base64
print(base64.b64decode('QnJpdGFpbidzIEdvdCBUYWxlbnQ=').decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks Goldwave, not familiar with encodings but this solved it.

Comment: No problem! They can look a bit intimidating when you first come across them, but baseXX is usually pretty straight forward.